# List with nested resources

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested

I have a Rails 3.2.1 application where:

```
  class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :category

  class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :articles
```

In routes:

```
   resources :categories, :shallow => true do
      resources :articles
   end
```

I want to display in my Articles#index all the categories with a list of their articles.
In my articles controller:

```
def index

#Categories
@categories = Category.all
@category = Category.find(params[:category_id]) if params[:category_id].present?
@category_articles = @category.present? ? @category.articles : Article.where("created_at >= ?", Time.now - 3.days).order("views DESC", :limit => 5).offset(1)
@feature_article = @category.present? ? @category.articles : Article.where("created_at >= ?", Time.now - 3.days).order("views DESC").first
end
```

My view (articles#index)

```
 <% @categories.each do |category| %>
<%= link_to category.name, category %> <!-- category name -->
    <%= link_to @feature_article.title, @feature_article %> <!-- feature article -->
    <% @category_articles.each do |article| %> <!-- Each category articles -->
              <%= link_to article.title, article %>
    <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

The problem is that it list all the categories but it seems not to respect the category_id param.
In each category it shows all articles, not the articles of each category.

Comment: you have problems only when you do that without `params[:category_id]` being set right? because when there is no such params @feature_article and @category_articles.

Comment: The first strange thing is, that if @category is not set, you will get all articles listed for each of your category (but maybe you need this). Try to simply access `p params[:category_id]` in your controller, and output it your log, then check your logs.

Comment: Sorry for answering too late, I think that I must find the category first and then display the articles of that category, but I have 12 categories listed in the articles#index. I´ll try your suggestions, thanks!